# MacOS plug and play for Android file transfert

Tags: macos, usb, android, file-transfer

I am following up from a question I have already asked on [Android Stackexchange back in 2015](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/117354/119828). We are now in 2023 and it looks like macOS and Android are still not able to pair well... I have still an enormous difficulties to transfert data between my Mac and my Android phone.

90% of the time when I connect my Pixel phone to my Macbook I get :

[image]

If I unplug and replug the cable multiples times, sometimes, by miracle, it works. So the issue is not the cable. Same issue with OpenMTP. My phone is well set up in USB debugging with File transfer as default USB config.

Airdroid is not an alternative for me as I would like to just be able to plug my Pixel into my Macbook and be able to navigate and transfert file. Is it really too much to ask ?

Am I the only one having this issue ?

Thanks for your insights !

---

PS : it's true that when I quit Google Drive, it's working most of the time, but is it really the only way to make it work ? It doesn't make sense...

Comment: This sounds **exactly** like a cable issue, As cables are cheap and returnable I would advise that first. And from a well known supplier of cables (Belkin, etc...) *"If I unplug and replug the cable multiples times, sometimes, by miracle, it works. So the issue is not the cable."*

Comment: "*it's true that when I quit Google Drive, it's working most of the time*" there's [an answer on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/251724/44325) observing the same behavior.

Comment: Exactly this is why I know this trick but nevertheless, I feel like it's not acceptable, right ? And the issue is not from the cable, 110% sure